# Failed to obtain response using Selenium python to automate visiting a website

Tags: python, selenium

Basically what I want to do is to automate visiting
[this website](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm). If you visit using Chrome, manually picking report type and date, a download link will appear. I tried to automate this process using python + selenium by
following the suggestions in the linked question. But selenium clicking the Get Data button didn't work. I don't know why. Please help.

Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/68598528/12469120 for more context about how to use DatePicker.

Her is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source":
        "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
        "delete newProto.webdriver;"
        "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
    })
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm")

time.sleep(5)
datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id("date")
datepicker.click()

selectMonth = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="ui-datepicker-month"]')
for option in selectMonth.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Mar':
        option.click() 
        break

selectYear = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="ui-datepicker-year"]')
for option in selectYear.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == '2018':
        option.click() 
        break 

days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-state-default"]')
days[4].click()
time.sleep(2)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('h_filetype'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Market Activity Report')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'getdata-button')))
element.click()
time.sleep(20)
```

### Update

The site can detect Selenium driven browsers. A workaround is added in the code. The download link can be obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, there is no file available for the specified date.

```
No file found for specified date. Try another date.
```

Though, there were some tweak needed, I have made some changes, see below :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='date']"))).click()

select_month = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-month']"))))
select_month.select_by_visible_text('Mar')

select_year = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-year']"))))
select_year.select_by_visible_text('2017')

days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='ui-state-default']")
days[3].click()
time.sleep(2)

select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "h_filetype"))))
select.select_by_value('fomkt')

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'getdata-button')))
element.click()
```

**Update 1:**

look, this css selector represent the **'file not available' message**

```
div#spanDisplayBox td
```

it's actually working manually, but hangs with automation (chrome browser). I have faced this issue earlier as well with the same site. However, I have added a method that could help us in following way :

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'getdata-button')))
element.click()

try:
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#spanDisplayBox td"))) > 0:
        print("Response is present")
        print(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#spanDisplayBox td"))).text)
    else:
        print("There is no response")
except:
    print("something went wrong")
    pass
```

However, when I ran this I got this output :-

```
There is no response
```

I would recommend you to check this with Firefox,  (cross browser, cross platform and see if that helps).

Comment: thanks for looking into it. Yes, the date I picked has no files. But the point is my code and yours showed no response (either the download link if available or 'file not available' message) from server.

Comment: @bssrdf : okay looks like issue with automation, you can get some idea if you look above into updated 1 section.

Comment: Thanks for your updates. You are right, that site can detect whether the browser is being automated by Selenium or not. I tried one trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65816505/12469120) and it worked (the download link showed up). I have updated my code with the trick.